# gtk+ Close second window

Tags: c, gtk

I have 2 froms, primary and secondary in my gtk+ application. In second from i have GtkButton - close. How can i close this form when button clicked. Not hide, i need close form.

Thank you

Comment: Which API you use to add the form to the main window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the form to the main window, in the callback function you can remove that from from the main window using the corresponding API and destroy the widget.

Your form is of type GtkWidget and hence you can remove and destroy the form. After this set the current form to the prev form on the main window. And `gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);`